# VBScipt Missing - Windows 7 64bit - Tried Many Solutions but No Luck

Tags: windows-7, script, troubleshooting, vbscript

When installing some programs or when trying to run .vbs files, Windows informs me it cannot find VBScript.

I have tried everything I can find online, including:

- Registering the .dll: `regsvr32 %systemroot%\system32\vbscript.dll` - I 
  get a successful message each time I register.
- Running `sfc /scannow`.
- Ensuring the registry key points the right place.
  `C:\Windows\system32\vbscript.dll` and not some anti-vir screening
  file.
- I can see the .dll file in both `system 32` and `sysWOW64`.

Any advice on how to proceed would be appreciated.  Also I cannot find any place where I might re-downloaded the VBScript engine.

More information:

The .vbs file format is associated with the Microsoft Windows Based Script Host.  This information is from the File Associations section of the Control Panel.

When I try to run a .vbs file I received an error window stating:

> Windows Script Host - Can't find script engine "VBScript" for script
>   "C:****.vbs".

Comment: are the .vbs files correctly associated? What is the exact syntax of the error message you receive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens when you run cscript.exe or wscript.exe? That's how you run (those) scripts on Windows.

It could be getting blocked by group policy, as well - I've heard of that being done in some corporate environments, though it was a temporary thing.

So, look for wscript.exe or cscript.exe, attempt to run them, see whether they're missing or what error message you get when running them, etc.

Comment: When I run csscript.exe `(C:\Windows\System32\cscript.exe)` it seems a command line box appears for a fraction of a second and then dissapears, nothing else happens.

When I run wscript.exe `(C:\Windows\System32\wscript.exe)` a window opens titled Windows Script Host Settings.

This error is occurring on my personal machine, no group IT settings are on it.

Comment: Try hitting Win-R (Windows key + r) then cmd.exe and press enter to open a command prompt that doesn't go away. Then try running cscript.exe.

Comment: Nothing happened.  I then dragged the cscript.exe file unto the cmd box.  It ran and I ended up with a bunch of commands under the title `Microsoft (R) Windows Script Host Version 5.8`.  Commands include `//B Batch mode` `//D Enable Active Debugging`. Screen cap here: (https://dl.dropbox.com/u/173617/cscript-cmd.png).

Comment: Great, that means it's working! Now, from the command prompt run: ASSOC .vbs followed by ftype VBFile. .vbs files work on my computer, and here's that those two commands say when I run them: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/98500946/vbs.jpg - if yours looks the same, then .vbs files should run. If yours looks different, then that is the problem.

Comment: I get exactly the same when I follow those steps.  It seems like everything is squared away but for some reason my machine just refuses to understand when it comes to actually running the files.

Comment: Ok, so try running your script from the command line - do the win+r cmd thing again, then run cscript.exe followed by the path and file name of your script.

Comment: Well that worked, thank you very much!  I also visited some websites with VBScript and created a few simple scripts and those worked as well.  I'm still getting the `Windows Script Host - Can't find script engine "VBScript" for script "C:****.vbs".` error with my main script as well as some installation problems with .exes that use VBScript but I'll put that down to something else.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

*Easy! I had the same problem before...  :/*

**Solution For Windows 7:**

1) Open "regedit".

2) Click yes if a dialogue box appears (for making changes to your computer).

3) Open: "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT".

4) Open: "CLSID".

5) Open: "{B54F3741-5B07-11cf-A4B0-00AA004A55E8}".

6) Click Once On: "InprocServer32".

7) Click Once On: "Current Version".

8) Double Click On "(Default)"

9) Where it says "Value Data", change that to "C:\Windows\System32\vbscript.dll".

---

*NOTE: If you had McAffee previously installed, it might have been "C:\Program Files\Common Files\McAfee\SystemCore\ScriptSn.20120217033008.dll" as the previous Data Value. Ignore this and follow step 9.*

---

10) Restart or shutdown the system.

11) Done! Simple as that.  :D

Hope this helps!   :)

Answer (score 0):

The error "Can't find script engine VBScript..." can occur if the dynamic link library (DLL) VBScript.dll isn't installed properly -- even if its physically on your system (as opposed to actually being missing).

Try to register it by entering `regsvr32 VBScript` followed by the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key at a Command Prompt or using the Windows Run command (which you can bring up by typing the <kbd>Win+R</kbd> key combination at the same time).

Comment: Done.  No change, still getting the same error window.